# Python: Calculate all values of dictionary to z-scores

Tags: python, dictionary, statistics

I have a dictionary, for which I want to calculate all values to zscores. Now I do know how to how to compute the zscore of an array, but have no idea how to do this for a dictionary. Does anybody have some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe what you need it to extract the list of values from the dictionary? If `d` is your dictionary, then you can do this by calling `d.values()`.

Comment: I tried the conversion to a list of values, but I don't understand how I can get them back together with its original key in the dictionary. (sorry if this is noobish of me...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is pure Python and calculates both mean and standard deviation (assuming 1 degree of freedom) in a single pass. It calculates the z-score values in a dictionary directly with a dict comprehension.

But note that according to the timing examples below, it is about 3x slower than re-zipping the results of `scipy.stats.zscore` with the dict keys (see `zify_scipy` below).

```
from math import sqrt

def zify(some_dict):
    arr = some_dict.values()
    sum_sq = x_bar = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        x_bar += val
        sum_sq += val * val
    n = 1 + i
    x_bar *= 1.0/n
    std = sqrt(1.0/i * sum_sq - (float(n) / i) * x_bar * x_bar)
    return {k:(v - x_bar)/std for k,v in some_dict.iteritems()}

test = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
print zify(test)

# {'a': -1.3363062095621223, 'c': -0.26726124191242445, 
#  'b': -0.8017837257372734, 'e': 0.8017837257372734,  
#  'd': 0.26726124191242445,  'f': 1.3363062095621223}
# compare with scipy.stats.zscore(test.values(), ddof=1)
```

Using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27082131/567620) based on `scipy.stats.zscore` (called `zify_scipy` below), we can set up some examples to test with `timeit`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip
from scipy.stats import zscore

def zify_scipy(d):
    keys, vals = zip(*d.items())
    return dict(zip(keys, zscore(vals, ddof=1)))

# test cases
test1 = dict(izip(range(1000),   np.random.randn(1000)))
test2 = dict(izip(range(10000),  np.random.randn(10000)))
test3 = dict(izip(range(100000), np.random.randn(100000)))
```

Then in an IPython session, I tested `zify` against `zify_scipy`:

```
In [411]: %timeit zify_scipy(test1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 407 µs per loop

In [412]: %timeit zify(test1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop

In [413]: %timeit zify_scipy(test2)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.43 ms per loop

In [414]: %timeit zify(test2)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 ms per loop

In [415]: %timeit zify_scipy(test3)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.8 ms per loop

In [416]: %timeit zify(test3)
10 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop
```

One note: whether you use the `zip(*d.items())` trick to get key/value arrays that are positionally matched, instead of first getting the values, then performing another iteration with the dict comprehension (as I did at the end of my implementation `zify`) does not seem to matter for timing. You're going to have to iterate through twice (once to calculate the mean/std, once to transform the values) either way.

A roughly 3x slowdown for pure Python is not that bad. For medium-sized use cases, I would feel comfortable with this as a means to avoid the extra dependency on scipy. But for a project already making use of numpy/scipy, go for `zify_scipy`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `d` is your dictionary and you want zscores of the values.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
keys, vals = zip(*d.items())
z = stats.zscore(vals)
newmap = dict(zip(keys,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use Scipy to calculate the Z-score and not manually

> from scipy import stats
>
> d = {'keys':values, ...}
>
> dict_values = d.values()
>
> z = stats.zscore(dict_values)

This will return a Numpy array with your z scores

Comment: thanks! how do I get the zscores back together with the corresponding keys?

Comment: do you mean a new dictionary with corresponding keys? then you can use dictionary comprehension: `new_dict = {(k,v) for (k,v) in zip(d.keys(), z)}`. edit: note that if you do this, it's better to use `from itertools import izip` instead of the normal `zip`

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you want to calculate the zscores of all values in a dictionay. and also assuming you know the mean and standard deviation

So what you would simply do is iterate over all the values and store the zscore in another dictionary with the same keys.
lets say dic is your dictionay

```
import numpy    
a={}
for key,value in dic.items():
    z=(value-mean)/standarDeviation 
    a[key]=z
```

a will contain all your zscores, with refernce to the same keys as in dic.

if you dont know first calculate mean and standard deviation as

```
mean=numpy.mean(dic.values())
standardDeviation= numpy.std(dic.values())
```

dic.values() returns a list of values in your dictionary

However I would use scipy and you can see why...
P.S. this would work well if the dataset is small, and you want to see how the data pans out...